# Password Validating Program

Tags: python, passwords, computer-science

I need to write a program that checks to make sure a password inputted by the user passes the following parameters:

- Contains at least eight characters.
- Contains no more than 24 characters.
- Consists of only letters, digits, and one of the special characters given below.
- Contains at least two upper case letters.
- Contains at least two lower case letters.
- Contains at least two digits.
- Contains one of the following special characters: !@#$%&*()_

I have everything working except for the "Consists of only letters, digits, and one of the special characters given below".

I have no idea what to write to check for this. Any ideas? Any tips on cleaning up the code or writing it more efficiently would also be appreciated.

```
password = input("Enter a password: ")

import re

def main():
upper = sum([int(x.isupper()) for x in password])

lower = sum([int(x.islower()) for x in password])

digit = sum([int(x.isdigit()) for x in password])

length = len(password)

special = re.search("[!@#$%&*()]", password)

if length >= 8 and length <=24:
    if upper >=2:
        if lower >=2:
            if digit >=1:
                if special:
                    print("Acceptable password.")
                else:
                    print("Unacceptable.")
main()
```

Comment: Every time I see a password constrains like your number 3. I know that the underlying password storage is most likely not safe and I avoid such services. Salt and hash the passwords and there is no need for such a constraint.

Comment: @KlausD. this is likely homework, not security.

Comment: Look into the built-in function `any()` and the operator `in`.

Comment: This is in fact a homework assignment.

Comment: @CoryNorell yes, and it is in fact *your* homework assignment, so it's not clear why you're here cheating on it.

Comment: By the way, if the entered password fails any checks other than the last one, there's no output.

Comment: I could see your point if I were asking someone to write the program for me, but I simply asked for direction. Is that not what sites like this are intended for - helping people learn? Collaboration?

Comment: ...no? Take the [tour].

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'll be sure to add outputs at each step, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pool of allowed characters and use the power of a `set` to check for unwanted characters.

```
import string
pool = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%&*()_'
```

This will give you `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%&*()_'`.

Now you can check the [`difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#set.difference) between the password and your pool of characters. Let your password be `'ABCD§12'`.

```
set(password).difference(pool)
```

This code will give you `{'§'}`.

So you just have to check for the length of the result of the difference. If it is `0` everything is fine.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!